# Add ggplot in layout command

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Why in this plot

```
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(2,2,2,2), mar=c(2,2,2,2),fin=c(4,4))

layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
                2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
                2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
                2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), nrow= 5,ncol=8,byrow = TRUE))

plot(1:100)
plot(1:100)

Map=get_map(location = c(lon = 12.50184, lat = 45.48403), zoom = 9, maptype = 'terrain', source="google", language = "it-IT")

ggmap(Map)
```

the map isn't added with the other two graphs in the layout described by `layout`?
(obvioulsly in my plot i haven't `plot(1:100)`, but some other plot)

Comment: You need package gridBase if you want to mix base and grid plots. ggplot2 is based on grid.

Comment: Can you give me a Little example?